# screen reader jump from my accordion

Tags: html, wai-aria, screen-readers

I have an accordion which is written internally in our company. I am using this as part of new page. Now there is problem with it, which is consider as a bug/defect.
The screen reader jump when it reach to accordion codes. and goes to next element.

```
<h4 class="accordion-header ng-scope ng-click-active" data-ng-click="vm.toggle(0)">
                        ABCDEFGHIJKLM------ [By January 1, 2014]
<button class="accordion-arrow" data-index="0">
    <svg version="1.1" class="svg-arrow-container" color-interpolation="auto" shape-rendering="auto" image-rendering="auto" text-rendering="auto" color-rendering="auto" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="-157 170.1 83.5 61.9" style="enable-background:new -157 170.1 83.5 61.9;" xml:space="preserve">
            <path class="st3 svg-arrow faq" d="M-77.2,204.8l-30.2-30.8c-0.3-0.3-0.5-0.6-0.8-0.9l-0.3-0.3c-3-2.9-7.5-3.5-11-1.7l0,0
                c-0.2,0.1-0.3,0.2-0.5,0.3c-0.1,0.1-0.3,0.2-0.4,0.2l-0.1,0.1c-0.5,0.3-0.9,0.7-1.3,1.1l-0.4,0.3c-0.2,0.2-0.3,0.3-0.5,0.5
                l-30.6,31.1c-3.7,3.7-3.6,9.8,0.1,13.4l0.3,0.3c3.7,3.7,9.8,3.6,13.4-0.1l24.3-24.5l24.2,24.6c3.7,3.7,9.7,3.8,13.4,0.1l0.3-0.3
                C-73.6,214.5-73.5,208.5-77.2,204.8z"></path>
    </svg>
</button>
</h4>

<div class="accordion-content medium" style="max-height: 330px;">
    <div class="inner">
        <p>
            We will communicate with people with disabilities in ways that .....
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I dont see any reason that screen reader pass this elements. Please suggest a solution that screen reader do not pass my accordion and reads its content.

Answer (score 0):

How did you navigate with screen trader ?
Your button doesn't contain any text.
Ng-click on a non-focusable tag...

It's  a start.